# I need to create a generic BehaviorSubject of boolean array to handle the loading spinner of the buttons on each page

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to create a generic BehaviorSubject of boolean array to handle the loading spinner of the buttons on each page, so I can start loading on the button after click and stop loading after success or error.

The issue that I am facing is if I have multiple buttons in the same page each button is calling different api so I need to start loading on the clicked button and stop loading on the same one.

If the api call fails or on success, I have to create multiple BehaviorSubject variables and multiple addLoading and removeLoading methods but this solution is not right and I need to make it dynamic.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsLoadingService {
  public isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)
  public isLoading2: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)
  public isLoading3: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)
  public isLoadingArr: BehaviorSubject<boolean[]>

  constructor() {
    let length = 10
    let array:boolean[] = []

    for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
      array.push(false)
    }

    this.isLoadingArr  = new BehaviorSubject(array) 
  }

  addLoading() {
    return this.isLoading.next(true)
  }

  removeLoading() {
    return this.isLoading.next(false)
  }

  addLoading2() {
    return this.isLoading2.next(true)
  }

  removeLoading2() {
    return this.isLoading2.next(false)
  }

  addLoading3() {
    return this.isLoading2.next(true)
  }

  removeLoading3() {
    return this.isLoading2.next(false)
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { IsLoadingService } from './is-loading.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { DataServiceService } from './data-service.service';
import { SimpleCrypt } from 'ngx-simple-crypt';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HandellErrorService {
  constructor(
    private _toaster: ToastrService,
    private route:Router,
    private _isLoadingService:IsLoadingService,
    private _userSerivce:UserService,
    private _dataService:DataServiceService
    ) { }

  /**
   * handleError
   */
  public async handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage: string
    this._isLoadingService.removeLoading()
    this._isLoadingService.removeLoading2()
    this._isLoadingService.removeLoading3()
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A Client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly
      errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`
    } else {
      //The back-end returned an unsuccessful response code.
      switch (err.status) {
        case 403:
          errorMessage = ` ${err.error.message}.`;
          this.updateUserObject()
          this.route.navigate(['welcome'])
          break;
       
        case 422:
          if (err.error.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
            errorMessage = ` ${err.error.message}.`;
          }else{
            errorMessage=JSON.parse(await err.error.text()).message
          }
          break;
       
        default:
          errorMessage = ` ${err.error.message}.`;
          break;
      }
    }
   
    this._toaster.error(errorMessage, 'Error')
  }

  updateUserObject() {
     
    this._userSerivce.updateUser().subscribe(res=>{
      let user =res['result']
      let objCrypt = new SimpleCrypt();

      user.token = objCrypt.encode("INNOVx123",JSON.stringify(user.token));
 
      sessionStorage.setItem('User',JSON.stringify(user))
     this._dataService.setUser(user)
   })
  }
}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEvent, 
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { HandellErrorService } from './handle-error.service';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HandellErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private _handellErrorService:HandellErrorService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return new Observable((observable)=>{
    next.handle(req).subscribe(
      //success
      (res:HttpResponse<any>)=>{
        if(res instanceof HttpResponse){
          observable.next(res);
        }
      },
      (err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
        //Handell Errors
        this._handellErrorService.handleError(err)
      }
    )
  })
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome"> 
    <div class="titlepage">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10"></div>
            <app-logo class="showLogo"></app-logo>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h4>Car Photos</h4>
                <h4><b>Upload</b></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

  <div class="row example-form">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 subtitle">
          Car Assets Photos
        </div>
      </div>
      <form  #carAssetsForm="ngForm" class="example-form">
        <div class="row">
       
          <div class="col-10 col-md-3">
           <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" >
             <mat-label>Car Plate No.</mat-label>
             <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="plate_number" placeholder="Car Plate No." maxlength="7" minlength="7" [formControl]="carPlateNoControle"   >
           
             <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoControle.hasError('maxlength')">
              The Car Plate No. must be 7 digit only
            </mat-error>
             <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoControle.hasError('minlength')">
              The Car Plate No. must be 7 digit only
            </mat-error>
             <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoControle.hasError('required') ">
              Car Plate No. <strong> required</strong>
            </mat-error> -->
           </mat-form-field>
            
          </div>
          <div class="col-1">
            <button mat-mini-fab (click)="getAssetNumber()" [disabled]="carPlateNoControle.invalid || !plate_number"  >

              <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="!isLoadingSearch " >
                search
              </mat-icon>

              <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoadingSearch " >
                <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20">
                </mat-spinner>
              </mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" >
              <mat-label>Car Type</mat-label>
              <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="car.type_desc" placeholder="Car Type"  name="car.type_desc" readonly>
              
            </mat-form-field>
           </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
           
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" >
              <mat-label>Car Model</mat-label>
              <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="car.model" placeholder="Car Model"  name="car.model" readonly>
              
            </mat-form-field>
           </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" >
              <mat-label>Car Color</mat-label>
              <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="car.color" placeholder="Car Color"  name="car.color" readonly>
              
            </mat-form-field>
           </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
           <!-- <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" > -->
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-6">
                 
                 <mat-label class="labelFont"><img [src]="carImgPlat"   class="imgupload"> Car Photo</mat-label>
                 <input type="file"  hidden #carPlateNoPhoto (change)="onFileSelected($event)" [formControl]="carPlateNoPhotoControle"  required >
               </div>
               <div class="col-5 createinputtel  createinputemail iconbluecolor">
               <p  class="labelFont" (click)="carPlateNoPhoto.click()">Select File&nbsp;
                 <i    class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </p>
             
             </div>
             <hr class="hrImag"> 
             </div>
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
            
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-4" >
            <img  *ngIf="this.carAssetImag"  [src]="this.carAssetImag" class="carimg">
         
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
            
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 ">
            <button mat-raised-button   class="yellowBtn" [disabled]="tempCarImgPlat || !asset_number || carPlateNoControle.invalid"  (click)="uploadPhoto()" >Upload
             <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoading " >
               <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20">
               </mat-spinner>
             </mat-icon>
   
            </button>
          </div>
         
   
         </div>
      </form>
     
   
    </div>
      
    <hr class="hrImag2"> 
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 subtitle">
          Car Types Photos
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="" class="example-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
           <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width"  >
             <mat-label>Car Type</mat-label>
             <mat-select [(ngModel)]="car_type" name="car_type" class="example-full-width"  [formControl]="carTypeControle"  >
               <!-- <mat-option>1</mat-option>  -->
               <mat-option *ngFor="let type of carTypes" [value]="type.id">
                 {{type.description}}
               </mat-option>
             </mat-select>
             <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="carTypeControle.hasError('required')">
               Car Type <strong>required</strong>
             </mat-error> -->
           </mat-form-field>
 
          
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
           <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" > 
             <mat-label>Car Model</mat-label>
             <input matInput  placeholder="Car Plate No." type="number" maxlength="4" name="model" min="2020" max="2025"   [formControl]="modelControle" [(ngModel)]="model"  >
             <mat-error *ngIf="modelControle.hasError('maxLength')">
               The Car Model must be 4 digit only
             </mat-error>
             <mat-error *ngIf="modelControle.hasError('max')">
               The Car Model must be between 2020 and 2025
             </mat-error>
             <mat-error *ngIf="modelControle.hasError('min')">
               The Car Model must be between 2020 and 2025
             </mat-error>
             <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="modelControle.hasError('required')">
               Car Model <strong>required</strong>
             </mat-error> -->
           </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
           
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
 
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6">
               <mat-label class="labelFont"><img [src]="carImg"   class="imgupload"> Car Photo</mat-label>
               <input type="file"   style="display: none" #addCarTypePhoto (change)="onImageSelected($event)"  >
             </div>
             <div class="col-5 createinputtel  createinputemail iconbluecolor">
             <p  class="labelFont" (click)="addCarTypePhoto.click()">Select File&nbsp;
               <i    class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </p>
             <!-- <p [hidden]="licForm.get('process_type') != 'LIC'">
               <i  (click)="onZoom(licUrl)" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
               <i  (click)="AddyourLicense.click()" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </p> -->
           </div>
           <hr class="hrImag3"> 
           </div>
          </div>
 
 
          
          <div class="col-4   "></div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-2   ">
 
         <button mat-raised-button  class="yellowBtn" [disabled]="modelControle.invalid || carTypeControle.invalid || cartempImg " (click)="uploadCarTypePhotos()">Upload
 
           <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoading2 " >
             <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20">
             </mat-spinner>
           </mat-icon>
         </button>
 
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <hr class="hrImag2"> 
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 subtitle">
             License
          </div>
        </div>
        <form  #carAssetsForm="ngForm" class="example-form">
          <div class="row">
         
            <div class="col-10 col-md-3">
             <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" >
               <mat-label>Car Plate No.</mat-label>
               <input matInput  [(ngModel)]="plate_numberForLicense" placeholder="Car Plate No." maxlength="7" minlength="7" [formControl]="carPlateNoForLicenceControle"   >
             
               <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoForLicenceControle.hasError('maxlength')">
                The Car Plate No. must be 7 digit only
              </mat-error>
               <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoForLicenceControle.hasError('minlength')">
                The Car Plate No. must be 7 digit only
              </mat-error> -->
               <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="carPlateNoControle.hasError('required') ">
                Car Plate No. <strong> required</strong>
              </mat-error> -->
             </mat-form-field>
              
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button mat-mini-fab (click)="getAssetNumber('LicenseFile')"   >
  
                <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="!isLoadingSearch " >
                  search
                </mat-icon>
  
                <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoadingSearch " >
                  <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20">
                  </mat-spinner>
                </mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
             <!-- <mat-form-field  class="example-full-width" > -->
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-6">
                   
                   <mat-label class="labelFont"><img src="../../assets/images/upload car.png"   class="imgupload"> {{licenseToUploade}}</mat-label>
                   <input type="file"  hidden #LicenseFile (change)="onLicenseFileSelected($event)" [formControl]="licenseFileControle"  required >
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-5 createinputtel  createinputemail iconbluecolor">
                 <p  class="labelFont" (click)="LicenseFile.click()">Select File&nbsp;
                   <i    class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </p>
               
               </div>
               <hr class="hrImag"> 
               </div>
            
            </div>
          
             
           
            <div class="col-2 ">
              <button mat-raised-button class="yellowBtn" [disabled]="carObj?.license_filename || carPlateNoControle.invalid"  (click)="uploadPhoto()" >Upload
               <mat-icon *ngIf="isLoading " >
                 <mat-spinner color="primary" diameter="20">
                 </mat-spinner>
               </mat-icon>
     
              </button>
            </div>
           
     
           </div>
        </form>
       
     
      </div>
    </div>
     

    <div class="row example-form">
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a custom loading directive for each button or with you have - a singleton loading service you can create a behavior subject with an key value pair object

```
loading=new BehaviorSubject({loading1:false,loading2,false})
// expose the behavior subject through a function that returns an observable 
// it lets you select your load key
isLoading=(key)=>this.loading.asObservable().pipe(pluck(key),distinctUntilChanged())
// dynamic method to set a loading key with value
setLoading=(key,value)=>this.loading.next({...this.loading.getValue(),{[key]:value}})
```

usage

```
// component
setLoading('loading',true)
// template
<button *ngIf="isloading('loading1') | async"> submit </button>
```